# Error loading appsettings.Production.json due to digest integrity issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, appsettings

I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly app with PWA enabled, and with files `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`. The last one is empty because it would contain secrets to replace when production environment is deployed to a kubernetes cluster.

I'm using k8s to deploy, and a `Secret` resource to replace the empty `appsettings.Production.json` file by an encrypted file, into a nginx based container with the published blazor app inside.

Now I'm getting this issue in the browser:
[image: Failed integrity validation on resource]

When the application was built using docker build in a CI pipeline, the file was an empty json file, and got a SHA computed that does not match then one computed by the build process.

**My question is**: How can I replace the `appsettings.Production.json` during deployment, much later than the build process, and don't have the integrity test failed over that file?

The file `blazor.boot.json` does not contain any SHA for the `appsetting.Production.json` file:

```json
{
  "cacheBootResources": true,
  "config": [
    "appsettings.Development.json",
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.Production.json"
  ],
  "debugBuild": false,
  "entryAssembly": "IrisTenantWeb",
  "icuDataMode": 0,
  "linkerEnabled": true,
  "resources": {
    "assembly": {
      "Azure.Core.dll": "sha256-rzNx\/GlDpiutVRPzugT82owXvTopmiixMar68xLA6L8=",
      // Bunch of .dlls,
      "System.Private.CoreLib.dll": "sha256-S7l+o9J9ivjCunMa+Ms\/JO\/kVaXLW8KTAjq1eRjY4EA="
    },
    "lazyAssembly": null,
    "pdb": null,
    "runtime": {
      "dotnet.timezones.blat": "sha256-SQvzbzBfueaAxSKIKE1khBH02NH2MJJaWDBav\/S5MSs=",
      "dotnet.wasm": "sha256-YXYNlLeMqRPFVpY2KSDhleLkNk35d9KvzzwwKAoiftc=",
      "icudt.dat": "sha256-m7NyeXyxM+CL04jr9ui1Z6pVfMWwhHusuz5qNZWpAwA=",
      "icudt_CJK.dat": "sha256-91bygK5voY9lG5wxP0\/uj7uH5xljF9u7iWnSldT1Z\/g=",
      "icudt_EFIGS.dat": "sha256-DPfeOLph83b2rdx40cKxIBcfVZ8abTWAFq+RBQMxGw0=",
      "icudt_no_CJK.dat": "sha256-oM7Z6aN9jHmCYqDMCBwFgFAYAGgsH1jLC\/Z6DYeVmmk=",
      "dotnet.5.0.5.js": "sha256-Dvb7uXD3+JPPqlsw2duS+FFNQDkFaxhIbSQWSnhODkM="
    },
    "satelliteResources": null
  }
}
```

But the `service-worker-assets.js` file DOES contains a SHA computed for it:

```js
self.assetsManifest = {
  "assets": [
    {
      "hash": "sha256-EaNzjsIaBdpWGRyu2Elt6mv3X+48iD9gGaSN8xAm3ao=",
      "url": "appsettings.Development.json"
    },
    {
      "hash": "sha256-RIn54+RUdIs1IeshTgpWlNViz\/PZ\/1EctFaVPI9TTAA=",
      "url": "appsettings.json"
    },
    {
      "hash": "sha256-RIn54+RUdIs1IeshTgpWlNViz\/PZ\/1EctFaVPI9TTAA=",
      "url": "appsettings.Production.json"
    },
    {
      "hash": "sha256-OV+CP+ILUqNY7e7\/MGw1L5+Gi7EKCXEYNJVyBjbn44M=",
      "url": "css\/app.css"
    },
   // ...
  ],
  "version": "j39cUu6V"
};
```

> NOTE: You can see that both `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Production.json` have the same hash because they are both the empty json file `{}`. But in production the second one is having a computed hash of `YM2gjmV5...` and issuing the error.

I can't have different build processes for different environments, because that would not ensure using the same build from staging and production. I need to use the same docker image but replacing the file at deployment time.

Comment: Maybe you can add an initContainer that mount the `appsettings.Production.json` from the secret, takes `service-worker-assets.js` from the docker image and replaces the hash value with computed hash value of the mounted file (using any `sed`-like tool) before storing the modified `service-worker-assets.js` in an `emptyDir` volumeMount. Then in the application container, mount the `emptyDir` volumeMount and mount and use that `service-worker-assets.js` instead.

Comment: That looks too hacky for me. I think that process could work but it is too brittle, and any change in the future could break that patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the `wwwroot/service-worker.published.js` file, which first lines are as follow:

```js
// Caution! Be sure you understand the caveats before publishing an application with
// offline support. See https://aka.ms/blazor-offline-considerations

self.importScripts('./service-worker-assets.js');
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(onInstall(event)));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(onActivate(event)));
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(onFetch(event)));

const cacheNamePrefix = 'offline-cache-';
const cacheName = `${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version}`;
const offlineAssetsInclude = [ /\.dll$/, /\.pdb$/, /\.wasm/, /\.html/, /\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.css$/, /\.woff$/, /\.png$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.gif$/, /\.ico$/, /\.blat$/, /\.dat$/ ];
const offlineAssetsExclude = [ /^service-worker\.js$/ ];

async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, { integrity: asset.hash }));
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}
...
```

I added an array of patterns, similar to `offlineAssetsInclude` and `offlineAssetsExclude` to indicate which files I want to skip integrity checks.

```js
...
const offlineAssetsInclude = [ /\.dll$/, /\.pdb$/, /\.wasm/, /\.html/, /\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.css$/, /\.woff$/, /\.png$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.gif$/, /\.ico$/, /\.blat$/, /\.dat$/ ];
const offlineAssetsExclude = [ /^service-worker\.js$/ ];
const integrityExclude = [ /^appsettings\.Production\.json$/ ]; // <-- new variable
```

Then at `onInstall`, instead of always returning a `Request` with `integrity` set, I skipped it for excluded patterns:

```js
...
async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => {
            // Start of new code
            const integrity =
                integrityExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url))
                ? null
                : asset.hash;

            return !!integrity 
              ? new Request(asset.url, { integrity }) 
              : new Request(asset.url);
            // End of new code
        });
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}
...
```

I'll wait for others to comment and propose other solutions, because the ideal response would set the correct SHA hash to the file, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: For me, I got the error `'Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('null'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.'`

But the general idea is great! Exactly what I've been looking for. I rewrote your snippet to return `new Request(asset.url)` instead of null, and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @PuerNoctis. I just edited the answer to reflect that issue. I forgot to update the answer when I detected this. I assume you can also use `undefined` instead of `null` for `integrity`, but I didn't tested it.